# How to mange resource hungry Istio default/SDS installation?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, amazon-eks

I'm using Istio at the moment combined with the [cert-manager](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-certmgr/). Because I need to have multiple certificates I'm using SDS instead of the volume mount approach.

But the hardware requirements for this stuff are really high. For GKE it is recommended to use a node-pool of 4x n1-standard-2 machines. This sums up to 200$ per month just for Istio. The recommendation for EKS is 2x m5.large machines. So it is a little bit cheaper but still around 150$. What confuses me is, that Minikube "just" needs 4vCPUs and 16GB memory in total which is round about the half of the requirements for GKE and EKS.

You'll see the resource hungry components by looking at the istio-system namespace, I mean especially the limits. For me it is:

- istio-telemetry > 1100m / 6800m (requested / limits)
- istio-policys (I have 5 of them) > 110m / 2000m

My question is:

1. Did you manage to reduce the limits without facing issues in production?
2. What node-pool size / machine type are your running your Istio plane?
3. Did someone tried auto-scaling for this node-pool? Did it reduce the costs?

Kind regards from Berlin.

Answer (score 0):

Managed Istio for GKE is offered by Google as a pre-configured bundle. `4x n1-standard-2` is recommended to provide enough resources for all Istio components being installed.

1. Downsizing a cluster below the recommended size does not make sense.
   Installation of managed Istio onto a standard GKE cluster (`3x n1-standard-1`) 
   will fail due to lack of resources. Besides that you wouldn't have 
   free computing capacity for your workloads. Recommended cluster size 
   seems reasonable.
2. Apart from recommended hardware configuration (`4x n1-standard-2`), 
   managed Istio can be installed and running on a cluster with configuration 
   `8x n1-standard-1`.
3. Taking into account mentioned in the point ##1, autoscaling could be beneficial 
   mostly for volatile workloads, but won't help that much for saving resources 
   allocated for Istio.

If the managed Istio for GKE seemed too resource consuming, you could install original version of Istio and select an installation profile with the components you actually need, as described here:

[Customizable Install with Helm](https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/helm/)

Comment: Thank you. I need to go for a custom installation because the managed Istio installation by GKE does not support SDS. I already tried and was really frustrated because I found almost no information about what I'm allowed to change when going with Istio managed by GKE and what profile is installed.